# Accessing clojure macro via namespace in which it was not defined

Tags: clojure

I've defined a macro in `func.clj`:

```
(ns my-library.func)

(defmacro my-macro [arg]
  `(identity ~arg))
```

and I want to bind it to a variable in `core.clj`:

```
(ns my-library.core
  (:require [my-library.func :as func])

(def my-macro-core func/my-macro)
```

so that I can do something like the following:

```
(ns script.core
  (:require [my-library.core :as mlc]))

(mlc/my-macro-core :boring-macro) ; -> :boring-macro
```

However, I can't do that because macros don't evaluate to a value. The following works:

```
(ns my-library.core
  (:require [my-library.func :as func])

(defmacro my-macro-core [arg]
  `(func/my-macro ~arg))
```

but it's redundant, so I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but it can be done:

```
(ns my-library.func)

(defmacro my-macro [arg]
  `(identity ~arg))

(ns my-library.core
  (:require [my-library.func :as func]))

(def ^:macro my-macro-core @#'func/my-macro)

(ns script.core
  (:require [my-library.core :as mlc]))

(mlc/my-macro-core :boring-macro)
```

The trick is to set the new var being defined to the raw function value of the macro being aliased, while setting the `:macro` metadata flag so the compiler recognizes it and calls it appropriately.

Comment: It seems that the @ is unnecessary. For example, `(def ^:macro my-or #'or)` yields a new macro `my-or` which works exactly like `or`. What is that? Thanks for the answer again.

Comment: The way I posted just avoids Var [indirection](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/6be05801ff060122bec43e4eac5fdddf5e174fcf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L374). Using the var itself is useful if you want subsequent updates to the var's value to be reflected in aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Potemkin's [import-vars](https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin#import-vars) supports macros:

```
(require '[potemkin :refer [import-vars]])
(import-vars [my-library.core my-macro])
```